# How use GoToState with DataTemplate in METRO app

Tags: c#, xaml, visualstatemanager

In my Page.Resources I have DataTamplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="gridviewQuestStyle">
        <Button Content="{Binding QuestNumb}" Style="{StaticResource buttonQuestStyle}"> 
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="questionStates">                        
                    <VisualState x:Name="Right">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="LightGreen" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Wrong">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BackgroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then I create GridView:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="GridView_ButtonsQuest"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource gridviewQuestStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" >
</GridView>
```

Questions is a List:

```
public class Question
{
    public string QuestNumb { get; set; }
    public string QuestText { get; set; }
}
```

The logic of my application is:

```
    if(isAnswerRight)
{
  VisualStateManager.GoToState(???, "Right", false);
}
else
{
  VisualStateManager.GoToState(???, "Wrong", false);
}
```

Please explain, what i need in first parameter in GoToState Method?

Answer (score 1):

If the VisualState Switch occurs in the .cs file for a Page or a UserControl (Not in an MVVM View Model). Apply a Name Property to the GridView

```
<GridView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="GridView_ButtonsQuest"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource gridviewQuestStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" 
    x:Name="myStateChanges" >
</GridView>
```

then and Stick it in the GoToState() method.

```
if(isAnswerRight)
{
  VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.myStateChanges, "Right", false);
}
else
{
  VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.myStateChanges, "Wrong", false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with a Listview. It is possible to get to the Control inside the template by using ItemContainerGenerator and VisualTreeHelper

```
foreach (var item in GridView_ButtonsQuest.Items)
{
    var gridItem = (GridViewItem)MyList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    var wrap1 =VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(gridItem , 0);
    var wrap2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(wrap1 , 0);
   ...
```

I used xmalspy to find out how many layers the control is wrapped in. Should be possible to build something that does this recursive.

The next problem I had is that you can't use GoToState with a grid or button. But someone had taken the time to devlop a ExtendedVisualStateManager that supports it see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/24dc19ff-15ed-4170-b3c3-d313728b642b

then you can write ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(...)